Why is my hard drive 8 times faster after replugging the USB hub it is attached to?
I noticed that my hard drive is 8 times faster after replugging the USB hub it is attached to. How is that possible?
My configuration:

Seagate Exos X22 20TB SATA 6Gb/s 7200RPM 3.5-inch Enterprise HDD (ST20000NM004E) (pic) connected via SABRENT USB 3.0 to SATA External Hard Drive Lay-Flat Docking Station (pic)
attached via USB to an Anker 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub (pic).
laptop MSI GS76 Stealth 11UH (mirror) with Windows 10 Pro 21H2.

More info:

I replugged the USB hub just a few seconds after unplugging it. I replugged it to the same USSB port on the laptop. I didn't do anything while it was unplugged.
No other programs is accessing the drive, at least not meaningfully (I monitor the disk activity via Windows Task Manager and Windows Resource Monitor).
I've noticed that behavior twice already over the past 4 days, so this is not a one-time fluke.


Before replugging the USB hub, the reading speed is ~37MB/s:

After replugging the USB hub, the reading speed is ~281MB/s with the same file:

After replugging the USB hub, the reading speed is ~284MB/s with a different file:


~37 MB/s is approximately the practical speed of a "480 Mbps" USB 2.0 connection. It implies that your hub couldn't reliably make a USB 3.x connection to the PC the first time, but successfully connected over both 2.0+3.x the second time.
The USB connector has two completely separate sets of pins for USB 2.0 and 3.x data, and the latter frequently fail to make contact in type-A ports, so it's not uncommon for devices to be detected as USB 2.0 instead.

The USB 3.0 pins are located at the very end, so if the connector is inserted only halfway in (or at a slight angle, or it's dirty), those pins won't make contact and the computer will only detect a USB 2.0 device.

Less obviously, because the USB 2.0 pins make contact before the USB 3.0 ones do, the computer waits a certain amount of time after detecting a USB 2.0 device for the 3.x connection to be established. (Or something along those lines.)
So if you're too slow plugging in the cable all the way in and the USB 3.0 pins don't make contact within ~0.5 seconds after the USB 2.0 connection, the device will stay detected as USB 2.0 only.
(I don't know whether this applies to hubs, given that they use 2.0 and 3.0 connections simultaneously, but it definitely applies to regular USB devices.)



Thanks, good catch!

@FranckDernoncourt Consider using USBView.exe or USB Device Tree Viewer as mentioned in Verifying USB connection speed (USB 3 or USB 2?) to check if has negotiated at USB 2.0 or 3.0 speeds.

@ChesterGillon thanks, that was indeed my follow-up question, will definitely do next time it goes down to 37 MB/s!

@ChesterGillon confirmed 3.0 for now when  reading speed is ~284MB/s  https://i.sstatic.net/V0RHvPJt.png I'll recheck if goes down to 37 MB/s
